# How to call some Clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking at the trie implementation in Clojure here:

http://merrigrove.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/clojure-implementation-of-dictionary.html

I'm struggling with the query-node-with-path function. How would I call it to return all child words of a stem?

I'm sure the secret is in the function call with the arguments

```
[ [ s & _ :as source ]
    {type :type children :children wf :word-fragment :as node}
    acc]
```

But I can't figure it out.

Comment: the 'secret' is argument destruction, see https://gist.github.com/edbond/8784899

Comment: this trie looks much simpler - http://pastebin.com/pdPuVBTi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the rest of the code, I think `query-node` is the function you want, it calls `query-node-with-path`, and only returns the part you want. Its two args expand to `source` and `node` (it's just defined poorly such that you don't know what its args are unless you look at the function it calls).

To actually explain the args to `query-node-with-path`

That is a [destructured](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms) argument list, describing three arguments:

- `source`, which is a sequence, and the first element is bound to `s`
- `node`, which is a hash-map, with keys `type`, `children`, and `word-fragment` bound to `type`, `children` and `wf`
- `acc` (which idiomatically means an accumulator argument)

It is clear that `acc` is added to as the function recurs, and it is an optional argument, since the function has another arity that creates `acc` as `[]` and calls the full arity version.

(As an aside, the code there is very inconsistently formatted, and harder to read than it should be)